# Изучение основ программирования

Tags: c++

Я учусь на инженера программного обеспечения на втором курсе. Нам дают всего по чуть-чуть, возникла нужда в самообразовании. Как я выяснил для себя, я плохо знаю основы и самому трудно написать программу. Решил самостоятельно пройтись по следующим темам: условия, циклы, массивы, указатели, функции, алгоритмы сортировки и поиска, структуры данных. Повыполнять упражнения с книги, пописать побольше. Как по мне, это и есть те базовые основы, которые должен знать любой программист. В качестве самоучителя возьму Дейтелов "Как программировать на С++". Для чего мне С++? Скорее всего, профессиональную деятельность не буду с ним связывать. Но я хочу начать с него, чтобы понять эти основы, описанные выше и основы ООП. Так, к примеру, в Java многое скрыто от пользователя, брать ее для изучения основ - не самый лучший вариант. После этого буду переходить на Java.

Покритикуйте ход моих мыслей и жду советов на счет того, как мне стоит заниматься.

Answer (score 3):

1. "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programms" (mitpress.mit.edu/sicp) и (поновее) "How to Design Programs" (www.htdp.org) (если в адресах не наврал). Есть ли на русском, не знаю. htdp задуман как замена sicp.
2. "How to think like computer scientist". (Варианты по языкам.)

Answer (score 2):

Как показывает практика, знание, вернее понимание принципов программирования, таких как работа с массивами, строками, файлами, функциями и т.д., - это только самое начало долгого пути. :) Потому что между твердым пониманием написанного в книжке примера и пониманием и владением набором инструментов для написания своих программ большое "растояние", по крайней мере на начальном этапе. Поэтому советую после прочтения определенного количества материала, лучше с взглядом наперед, тут же пробовать свои силы на практике, не поверите, сколько поначалу, да и не только, возникает неожиданных вопросов, порой даже нелепых, но на фоне малого опыта, кажущихся очень трудными. Плюс практика, лучший способ как понимания, так и запоминания, наработки навыков: можно прочесть очень много литературы, но без практики так делеко и не уйти.

На счет выбора языка, тут вопрос на мой взгляд неоднозначный, с одной стороны, тот же С++ в полном его свете очень обширный, зачастую избыточный для многих задачь, но, в тоже время, требующий знания мелочей, так как без них ничего более менее стоящего не написать и не понять кода другого человека, писавшего до Вас. С другой стороны, существуют языки менее всеобъемлющие, более узкоспециализированные, так сказать, изучение которых займет меньше времени и скорее даст возможность писать реальные приложения. Хотя может и не раскроют всех сторон программирования как такового, тут решайте сами, что вам потребуется в будущем.

А вот на счет того, что инженеру потребуется знание и понимание алгоритмов постороения программных средств, это сто процентов, знание принципов, подходов, стратегий написания программ, очень важно, плюс умение правильно разбить, декомпозировать задачу - очень ценные и высокооплачиваемые навыки. Зачастую бывает так, что человек, из которого знания просто сыплются, изначально допускает обидные просчеты в выборе структуры своей будущей программы, за что в последствии и страдает, а часто и не он один:)

Если подытожить, советую обязательно уделить внимание общим стратегиям построения программ, тем более, что непосредственный труд программиста не предвидится, по крайней мере, в ближайшее будущее. Удачи.

Answer (score 1):

C++ - это конечно хорошо, но очень долго. Как правило, все начинают с C++, а потом переходят либо на C#, либо на Java, либо на Obj-C и только потом уже начинают писать серьёзные проекты. Сейчас довольно хорошо развивается Ruby - его позиционируют как язык, понятный для программиста, а не для компьютера, поэтому если бы у меня была возможнсть начать с нуля, то я начал бы с него. Литературу советовать не буду, так как в этом плане вам лучше спросить у преподавателей - они посоветуют лучшее.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я бы посоветовал изучить алгоритмизацию и средства языка в таком порядке:

- переменные; (Как же без них?)
- условия во всех их видах и логические операции; (И, ИЛИ, НЕ, исключающее ИЛИ, сравнения и т.д.)
- циклы; (С перечислениями: for, foreach, если изучаемый язык имеет, и условные: while и т.д.)
- функции и процедуры; (Хотя бы как обращаться к ним, и что они умеют)
- массивы; (Просто как упорядоченное собрание всякого, создание и удаление, статическое и динамическое, перебор, поиск элемента в нём)
- указатели как способ работы с массивами и переменными; (Передача по указателю в функцию), если язык позволяет (Остальное потом)
- структуры; (Зачем они нужны)
- классы и основы ООП. (объекты, переменные, методы и свойства, области их видимости)

Ну а далее уже по потребностям.
Алгоритмы сортировки и поиска можно приткнуть как практическое применение знаний о массивах, функциях и условиях. Ну и проверить навыки алгоритмизации свои.
Как обязательное условие - для всех пунктов практика. Желательно много.

Начать желательно с любого языка, который позволяет структурное программирование. С, С++, паскаль да хоть Basic в любой из своих инкарнаций. Потом - ООП.

Comment: >> Basic в любой из своих инкарнаций  - одной из них является Spectrum Basic - он не был структурным ;)

Comment: Не, это англоязычная транслитерация языка "Васик" для ПЭВМ "Микроша". (Название журнала уже не помню).
А вообще изучение программирования на основе Бэйсков-Паскалей кажется суровым анахронизмом. Ruby - может быть, но уж больно в нём некоторые части перловые.

Comment: Можете конкретнее разъяснить обязательное условие - практика? Где стоит брать упражнения, на чем можно попрактиковаться еще и т.д, вот эти моменты не могли бы разъяснить.

Comment: Ну, приукрасил немного =) Я про современные басики. Там есть и ничего среди них.

Да, зато там вполне себе нормальные конструкции циклов, условий, процедур, достаточно чёткая типизация. Руби как-то слишком уж ООП. Да и всякой бе для начинающего, как по мне, много. Запутается.

Comment: Хм, упражнения. Думаю, можно взять и из школьной информатики, какого-либо учебника =) На основы задачки все, в общем-то, не требуют от языка чего-то особого и они более-менее простые. С ООП потруднее, не помню, есть это в школе или нету .-.

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите PASCAL, простой язык, никаких синтаксических изощрений. Правда, учить по нему ООП, не знаю как, не приходилось. Но с базовыми вещами разбираться проще, чем в том же C.

Answer (score 0):

Можно начать с Basic

```
10 A = 10
20 B = 10
30 cout << A + B;
```

Comment: На басик это как-то не особо смахивает .з.

Answer (score 0):

Для программиста, тем более инженера - главное: уметь СОСТАВЛЯТЬ алгоритмы решения задач. Выбор языка вторичен. Для целей ОБУЧЕНИЯ программированию стоило бы взять язык попроще, а потом переходить к языкам помощнее.

Comment: Тогда ответ однозначен - Scheme. Проще вряд ли найдёте. Для изучения задач классической механики (mitpress/sicm) данный язык был выбран именно поэтому . И среда plt-scheme для изучающего весьма впечатляет.

Answer (score 0):

На [cyberguru.ru](http://cyberguru.ru) сборник книг. Я оттуда много, что смотрю, скорее всего, там вы найдете все, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Я учусь на Компьютерном и Математическом моделировании. Нам на 1-курсе преподают ФОРТРАН.
Он простой. Дали три части задачника Абрамян и решайте. К примеру:

```
program summa
    integer::a,b,c
    print*,'Enter A'
    read*,a 
    print*,'Enter B'
    read*,b
    c=a+b
    print*,c
end program
```

Comment: Ну математическое моделирование и программирование, они как бы различаются :-)

Comment: Ну, как вам объяснить, это как бы новая специальность: МКМ(математическое и компьютерное моделирование).